# Isolated storage available space equals 0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I tried to increase available space for our app, but when I call `isolatedStorageFile.IncreaseQuotaTo(1024*1024*30);`, nothing happens. Also `isolatedStorageFile.AvailableFreeSpace` equals 0. Why could it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your call to IncreaseQuotaTo is not user-initiated (i.e.: within a button-click handler, or something similar). In order for this method call to succeed, it must be initiated by the user, not by code.

Also, if you're debugging and have a breakpoint in your code, anything that happens after the breakpoint is not considered to be user-initiated, no matter where the code is executed.